# fix the display format in php when trying to retrieve data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, echo

i am using **PHP** with **MYSQL** database in order to retrieve some data  i used the below query :

```
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results('select siteID, siteNAME, equipmentTYPE from `site_info`  where ownerID = 159');
foreach($result2 as $result) {
    print_r ($result);
    echo "<br/>";
```

but this query return this format :

```
stdClass Object ( [siteID] => BAH004 [siteNAME] =>XXXXXXX [equipmentTYPE] => XXXXXXX )
```

where i want the format to be like this :
**BAH004, XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX**

can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wpdb::get_results](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/), you can use `ARRAY_N`

> wpdb::get_results( string $query = null, string $output = OBJECT )
>   $output
>
> (string) (Optional) Any of ARRAY_A | ARRAY_N | OBJECT | OBJECT_K constants. With one of the first three, return an array of rows indexed from 0 by SQL result row number. Each row is an associative array (column => value, ...), a numerically indexed array (0 => value, ...), or an object. ( ->column = value ), respectively. With OBJECT_K, return an associative array of row objects keyed by the value of each row's first column's value. Duplicate keys are discarded.
>
> Default value: OBJECT

So, using

```
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results('select siteID, siteNAME, equipmentTYPE from `site_info`  where ownerID = 159', ARRAY_N);
```

should do the trick.

---

To have the desired output format, you must not use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), because `print_r` output has a fixed format. Rather do the output yourself, e.g.

```
foreach($result2 as $result) {
    echo join(', ', $result), '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: your answer was not completely right because it returns **Array ( [0] => BAH004 [1] => xxxxxx [2] => xxxxxxx )**